# Drop Down Firefox in ubuntu

Tags: firefox

Is there any way we can have Firefox the way we can have terminal with `Tilda` or `Guake`?

Comment: I would love to see this answered

Comment: I doubt there is a version currently available that can make firefox drop down, but it would be nice to have something so it can run in the background when closed... (EDIT: for that, the [MinimizeToTrayRevived](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/minimizetotray-revived/) extension works, requires some fiddling has to be done in settings first :).

Comment: @Wilf thanks Wilf. I wish you had sent this as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is a version currently available that can make Firefox drop down, as that would require a patch or rather large amount of work on the extension.

However, an alternative that so you can open Firefox quicker would be to use the [MinimizedToTrayRevived](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/minimizetotray-revived/) extension. This means that instead of closing Firefox minimizes to tray instead.
In Gnome 3 this in the message tray - you have to click on this, as using the default launcher will launch a new instance of firefox: 
[image]

You may have to some fiddling in the settings first:
[image]

Comment: Combined with the [TopIcons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/) GNOME Shell extension, is how I get Thunderbird to stay out of my way.

Comment: Hmm probably should move back to thunderbird cos Evolution is always in my way (won't check in background) :(

Answer (score 0):

You could make your Firefox window sticky and then use the **xdotool** command and write a script that hides your window (move it all the way off screen) and shows it when you press a key.  Or minimizes the window when you press a key.